# iPad 2 freezes constantly on the same wifi network an iPhone 6 works smoothly

Tags: iphone, ipad, internet, router

I have an iPad 2 and an iPhone 6 on the same wifi network.

Making a facetime call using the iPad is a nightmare. The video freezes constantly. An iPhone 6 on the same wifi works like silk.

My internet is DOCSIS, cable 35 MBPS down and 3 MBPS up.

My ISP replaced the old router I had (a motorola) with a new more "modern" design a (thompson DWG874B).

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one device works fine on the network with a network-bound app and the other does not then it is not likely the fault of the network. And as you have replaced the WiFi router on your network and it *still* has problems you need to look at the iPad.

The first thing I would do is reset the iPad's network settings like this:

```
Settings > general > Reset > reset network settings
```

If that does not fix the issue I would back up the iPad to your Mac/PC via iTunes and go back to:

```
Settings > general > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings
```

And wipe the iPad. Once you do that restore it from the backup you just made and try again.

Comment: BRILLIANT! This appears to have solved 90% of the problem. The iPad still freezes eventually but it is way better. THANKS

Comment: Oddly enough resetting network settings will often fix a multitude of iOS problems as the network (Cellular and WiFi) are central to its functioning.

Comment: OK, the ipad improved a lot but the problem is still there.